# What does getTrace() method do in php ? What is stack?

Tags: php, exception

I am new to php and learning it from **php.net**. Can any one tell what is stack and why we use **getTrace()** method in php ?

When i use following code:

```
try{
    throw new Exception("Custom exception");
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo print_r($e->getTrace(),true);
}
```

It returns the following

```
Array()
```

Can anyone tell what does **getTrace()** method do in php? What is stack ?

Comment: Short answer: `getTrace()` returns the stack, which is an array containing a list of functions passed through to get to the point at which the exception occurred, and which file and line called that function. For more information, see the [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function.

Comment: So why it does not returns anything when called in global scope ?

Comment: And what is stack ?

Comment: Like I said, the stack is an array of **functions** passed through to get to a particular point. In the global scope, you haven't passed through any functions but are just working linearly (top-to-bottom, one line of code at a time), so the stack will be empty. You can output a combination of `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` to figure out where you are in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function, PHP keeps track of where in the code the call was made from, so that it can know where to go back when you exit that function. It uses the stack as that record of function calls, even when you call one function from within another function.

e.g

If I have the following code:

```
1. function a($value1, $value2) {
2.    return $value1 / $value2;
3.  }
4.
5. function b($value1) {
6.    return a($value1 / 12);
7. }
8.
9. echo b(12);
```

A reference to line 9 will be puhed onto the stack when PHP executes that line of code and calls function `b()`. When function `b()` calls function `a()`, then a reference to line 6 will be pushed onto the stack. When function `a()` executes the return, it looks at the stack, and know that it has to continue executing the code from line 6 (the last entry on the stack). It removes that stack entry and continues executing the rest of the code from line 6, which is the return from function `b()`, so it looks to the stack again and finds the reference to line 9, so it knows that it needs to continue executing the code from line 9 again, removes that entry from the stack and carries on executing from line 9.

The stack is also use to hold details of all the arguments passed to functions, so it holds a lot of detailed information

`getTrace()` lists all those reference points that are in the stack, and the arguments passed to functions.

Comment: I used this method in class, it also returns class name and its method name from where the **getTrace()** is called.

Comment: Yes it will, because getTrace() is a function like any other function, so the call to getTrace() itself will also be pushed onto the stack

Comment: No i mean it return the class name slong its method name of the class where the **getTrace()** is called.

Comment: So that is why **getTrace()** method does not returns an empty array in global scope, ha ?

Comment: Yes. it knows where the script need to continue executing..... so it stores the point in the code that it needs to return to..... from that, it can identify the class and method details of the call, as well

Comment: Correct. When called in the global scope, there is nothing on the stack, so nothing to return

Comment: According to my knowledge, i hope php use FIFO in its stack, Is that correct ?

Comment: No, a queue is FIFO, a stack is LIFO

Comment: You mean the job which was lastly(newly) inserted into the stack will be executed first so called LIFO , ha ?

Comment: When you "pop" an item off the stack, then it will be the last entry that was "pushed"

Comment: So exactly what i say that the newly entry is the last entry inserted into the stack, so it is LIFO,  yes ?

Comment: Yes, a stack is LIFO

Comment: Can you help to understand one more thing. The **getPrevious()** method. Please

Comment: Please answer here i have asked the question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554604/wharwhat-does-getprevious-method-do-in-php